Does Kafka Fetch All Topic Metadata on Spring Kafka Consumer Listener?
I have a default-consumer-group to consume kafka messages and try to fetch all topics with it but sometimes unexpectedly, consumer-group tries to access other topics (most probably only for consumer-metadata)... I catch this access from authorization because I have topic-based-authorization.
An example consumer for simple topic looks like:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TopicMessageHandler {
    private final UseCaseHandler useCaseHandler;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1",
            containerFactory = KAFKA_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY,
            groupId = "default-consumer-group")
    public void handle(ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord,
                       @Payload MyPayload payload,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID) String groupId,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) int partition) {
        useCaseHandler.handle(payload);
    }
}

this "default-consumer-group" is used on multiple topic-consumer-listeners (topic1, topic2) with similar way. But all of topics have different authorizations...
When I try to consume topic1, sometimes I got errors about topic2 as you are not authorized to topic2. so I wonder that Does Kafka-listener try to fetch all-topic-metadata-consumer relations? and if yes, is there a way to avoid it?
Note: Please don't confuse with authorization part, mentioned for only log purposes. The real question is Does Spring-kafka-listener try to fetch all-topic-metadata-consumer relations, if I use same consumer-group-id?
